# ios force back button style w/ no navigation controller

Tags: ios

I'm not using a navigation controller so I'm just getting a plain rounded rect. I want to get the arrow-esque back button instead, is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Find and set image for button

Comment: Any reason you're not using a navigation controller? What with you having a navigation bar, and a back button, which presumably takes you back, it seems like you're making things difficult for yourself.

Comment: @jrturton I agree that would be easier, the design just doesn't allow any room for a navigation controller bar at the top of the FIRST frame, only the second.

Comment: @Jackson in that case, my answer might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you would like to use a navigation controller but don't have room for the navigation bar on your root view controller.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden
```

Will hide or show the navigation bar within a view controller. That should make your life simpler.

Comment: this is the correct way. And use [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: animated:] in your viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear methods to get the navigation bar to appear naturally.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather simple, create your custom back button like so:

```
UIButton *button = /* your custom button, most likely with an image */

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using an image? I'm guessing not.